# WebRTC not working behind a VPN

Tags: webrtc, turn, simplewebrtc, coturn

The video chat works with most users, but I couldn't get a video chat to work with one of the user of my website.
She couldn't see me, and I couldn't see her.

I don't have any details how it failed like if it was at the SDP negotiation, or if she failed a connection to our TURN server (coturn), but hopefully someone has made it work for VPN users and has an answer for this issue.

Comment: Are you using any TURN servers…?

Comment: I had to configure TURN on the JavaScript client and coturn server to make WebRTC work with a VPN.

Answer (score -2):

ICE failures can happen, no matter what. The ice connection state will go to failed and simplewebrtc will give you an iceFailed event [here](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/simplewebrtc.js#L172-L174). You'll need to handle that in your UI somehow.

Comment: Sure I handle failure but my goal is to make it work at the first place. The video chat between her and me worked on other video chat services.

Comment: what services? If it works on apprtc, talky or appear.in but not on your service you might want to check your turn configuration, most importantly whether you get relay candidates on both sides.

If it doesn't work there you might hit the limits of webrtc...